# Javascript value is returned from webservice but will not show unless a breakpoint is used

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript function that calls a web service.  The data comeback (I see the Jason return in FireBug) the value is blank when I attempt to use it unless I set a break point.  With a break point set the value can be used, without it is not available.

Here is a snippet of the offending call.

```
function getTheNote(noteCode){
    var _myNote = "";
    var theID = $('#CustNo').val();
    var myDTO = { 'theID': theID, 'noteCode': noteCode, };
    var toPass = JSON.stringify(myDTO);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "AR_Cust_Mgt.aspx/getNote",
        data: toPass,
        success: function (data) {
                _myNote = data.d;

        }    
    });
    //setTimeout(_myNote += _myNote, 120000);
    //for(var x = 0; x < 200000; x++){}                              
    //return _myNote;
    alert(_myNote);


 }
```

Originally I was sending the value back to a calling function the return statement is where I would set my break point and the data would be returned, without nothing.  Now you can see I attempted to use an alert inside the function with the same results.

With a break point I get a value without I get nothing, I have even attempted to use some delays.

Please help.

Comment: Because the call is asynchronous, execution doesn't stop there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

small change, big difference: you are not calling alert IN the succes function

```
  success: function (data) {                 
    _myNote = data.d;          
    alert(_myNote);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, not sure why I blew that one.  I should have known better

Answer (score 2):

The ajax call is asynchronous. Anything you want to do with the result needs to be in your anonymous function `success: function(data) { ...` or the anonymous function needs to call other functions to do stuff.

As it is coded now, $.ajax will be called, the script execution continues on before the ajax call returns.

Comment: Thanks, I knew that just must have had a complete melt down